# Unchecked call to method as a member of raw type

Tags: java, android, generics, interface, generic-interface

Following warning is shown in my project -

Unchecked call to 'getWeatherData(T,Boolean,String)' as a member of raw type 'IWeatherCallbackListener'.

I have created following interface -

```
public interface IWeatherCallbackListener<T> {
 void getWeatherData(T weatherModel, Boolean success, String errorMsg);
}
```

And called it in following way,

```
public class WeatherConditions {

private static IWeatherApi mWeatherApi;

/**
 * @param city
 * @param appId
 * @param listener
 */
public static void getOpenWeatherData(String city, String appId, IWeatherCallbackListener listener) {

    mWeatherApi = ApiService.getRetrofitInstance(BASE_URL_OPEN_WEATHER).create(IWeatherApi.class);
    Call<OpenWeatherModel> resForgotPasswordCall = mWeatherApi.getOpenWeatherData(appId, city);
    resForgotPasswordCall.enqueue(new Callback<OpenWeatherModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OpenWeatherModel> call, Response<OpenWeatherModel> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.getWeatherData(response.body(), true, "");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<OpenWeatherModel> call, Throwable t) {
            if (listener != null)
                 listener.getWeatherData(null, false, t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I have implemented this interface in my MainActivity and called the method   as -

```
WeatherConditions.getOpenWeatherData(etCityName.getText().toString(), OPEN_WEATHER_APP_ID, MainActivity.this)
```

Can anyone please help and explain this warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you have to declare your `T` type too, in your case it has to be a class of `response.body()` instance.

Try to replace line

```
public static void getOpenWeatherData(String city, String appId, IWeatherCallbackListener listener)
```

to

```
public static void getOpenWeatherData(String city, String appId, IWeatherCallbackListener<ResponseBody> listener)
```

That is so because when you declare your interface

```
IWeatherCallbackListener<T>
```

You use T and its raw type. When you create instance you have to show what **exactly** type you will use or what exactly type you want to receive as argument.

For example if you create that listener manually that had to look like this

```
IWeatherCallbackListener<ResponseBody> listener = new IWeatherCallbackListener<ResponseBody>() {
    //implementation of methods
}
```

Same thing for arguments, you have to show what `T` you can receive.

Comment: thanks @DEADMC your solution is working perfectly fine, but can you please explain it because I did not understand this concept.It would be a great help.